# Why isn't the conversion constructor called?

Tags: c++

I've made a simple class just to try the conversion constructor in C++.

It works apparently, but when doing a certain operation, it seems that the compiler doesn't call it. I would know why, or maybe where I'm wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

class CostruttoreConversione
{
public:  
  CostruttoreConversione(int val = 0)
  {
    cout << "Costruttore chiamato" << endl;
    valore = val;
  }

  inline int getValore(){
    return valore; 
  }

  CostruttoreConversione provaConversioneImplicita()
  {
    return -10; //here the type *should* be converted; doesn't happen.
  } 

private:
  int valore;
};

int main(void){
  CostruttoreConversione obj(10);
  cout << "obj = " << obj.getValore() << endl;
  obj = 20; //WORKS 
  cout << obj.getValore() << endl;
 // cout << obj.provaConversioneImplicita() << endl; doesn't work.
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You don't need to declare functions `inline` when they are defined in the class; it has the same effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The construction should work, but it's the output operation that fails because you haven't defined an output operator for your class.

You could still do e.g.

```
cout << obj.provaConversioneImplicita().getValore() << endl;
```

Or you define an output operator:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CostruttoreConversione& cc)
{
    os << cc.getValore();
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Note that when you return -10 from ConstruttoreConversione::provaConversioneImplicita(), it returns a temporary so the valore member variable of instance on which that fundtion was invoked will *not* be modified.

Comment: You are right. My thought was wrong.
I've totally forgotten to implement the << operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload conversion operator so that CostruttoreConversione can convert to int.

```
class CostruttoreConversione{
  operator int() const{
     return valore;
  }
}
```

also write a copy constructor

Answer (score 0):

The default constructor and the parameterised constructor together constitute a conversion constructor.
For example,
If you are writing a program for creating an ADT array,
when you declare a variable of data type array in the function main,
main calls the parameterised constructor which is converting the array into the data type you used to develop array.
So indirectly conversion is happening.
Therefore the conversion constructor is not called.
But the default and the parameterised constructor do the conversion internally.